# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: timetable

Tags: python

I'm missing a table called 'timetable'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samsshow\Desktop\microsoft-teams-class-attender-main\bot.py", line 265, in <module>
    add_timetable()
  File "C:\Users\samsshow\Desktop\microsoft-teams-class-attender-main\bot.py", line 108, in add_timetable
    c.execute("INSERT INTO timetable VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')"%(name,start_time,end_time,day))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: timetable
```

Comment: Are you sure it's called timetable and not 'time_table' or 'timetables'?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the table? If not:

```
CREATE TABLE timetable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), start_time DATETIME, end_time DATETIME, day DATE);
```

If you already did, maybe you misspelled your table name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the table `timetable` in your database, but you probably already figured this out.

It's impossible to say anything else based on the information you provided. What are you trying to do? What have you tried? Error log is not enough.